# Unable to copy objects between versions

Tags: versions

I can't copy and paste objects between versions

[image]

[image]

which is an issue because older blender crashes trying to open newer blender files and newer blender warps models from older blender on scaling

Comment: I don't believe the statement "newer Blender warps models from older Blender on scaling" is true. Could you clarify what you mean by "older Blender" and "newer Blender"? Is it 2.79 and 2.80 or is it older 2.80 build and newer 2.80 build?

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into what I believe is [the same issue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167364/copy-and-paste-between-2-79-2-80-and-2-81a).

Check the **Temp** path in both versions' preferences. You probably changed it for the old version in the past but forgot to do this in the new installation. You must use the same path otherwise the clipboard contents won't get shared across versions.

What's happening is that upon copying an object Blender temporarily stores it in a file called *copybuffer.blend*, found in the temp directory. When the temp path isn't the same in all versions preferences you'll get independent *copybuffer* files in those  different directories, and each Blender version will only read the files from their respective temp directories.

Here's how to setup the temp directory path:

## 2.79 and earlier

*Temp* in **File** tab of  **File > User Preferences**

[image: Preferences in 2.79-]

## 2.8+

*Temporary Files* in **File Paths** tab of  **Edit > Preferences**

[image: Preferences in 2.80+]

Answer (score 1):

Here is screenshot from www.blender.org :

[image]

I would like to direct your attention to the line :

**"Although it is absolutely not recommended for use on production environments."**

It seems you are observing some of the reasons why this warning exists.

It is possible to read data saved in 2.79 with 2.80, but not the other way around. This is to be expected.