# Copy and paste between 2.79/2.80 and 2.81a+

Tags: workflow

I keep multiple Blender versions due compatibility reasons. In the past when I needed to transfer an something from an already open 2.79 file to a 2.80 file I could simply copy the object, Alt+Tab to the 2.80 window, paste it. No need to go the extra steps of diving in the *Append* file explorer and navigating all the way to the right folder and object when I already got it selected in another Blender instance.

The same can't be done in 2.82. It's like 2.82 uses a clipboard apart from past Blender versions. Whatever is sitting there can't be overwritten by objects coming from 2.80 and older instances. I dug up a 2.81a version I downloaded some months ago but never touched and it seems to suffer from the same issue, sharing this separate clipboard with 2.82.

End result: I can only copy object between 2.81a and 2.82 instances.

Is that a bug with my installations? Am I doing something wrong? Or is this lack of backward compatibility of the clipboard by design?

Comment: Hello :). Everything works just fine on my end 2.8/2.81/2.82 copy object without problems. Don't have 2.79 any more.

Comment: @JachymMichal I just wanted to thank you for commenting. Knowing it *was* supposed to work as I expected encouraged me to do some extra digging, and the reason behind this issue couldn't be more silly, hah: It's the temp path!

The new versions were installed using the zip folder, meaning 100% factory settings. I overlooked the temp path 2.81a+, meaning their copybuffer.blend was, indeed, apart from the versions with the custom temp path. Well... Now we know how to quarantine the copybuffer, if we ever need it.

Comment: Thanks for your digging :). Would you mind posting your comment as a full answer? I'm sure it will be helpful to other lost souls :).

Comment: @JachymMichal Working on it. Now I know what I'm looking for (*not* a 2.81a/2.82-specific issue) I discovered an older question that must be due the same issue. I think I should post the solution there and close my question instead.

I'll link the older question here just in case I can't mark my own question as duplicate when closing: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140407/unable-to-copy-objects-between-versions