# Appearing of unkown file name in autosave recover

Tags: blend-files

[image]]

I saved my file today with name riot face making.blend but i found i did mistake so i thought to recover the yesterday progress. So as soon i opened recover autosave i saw a file name copybuffer.blend .

[image]

When i opened it i saw that it loaded with caution sign reporting about library file loaded with empty scene. Please tell me if i should be concerned or not , is anyone trying to copy my file through different computer or device ? I never made or saved any file with name copybuffer .

Comment: Have a read of the first answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140407/unable-to-copy-objects-between-versions).